# plotting a {{Latitude,Longitude}} list on top of a GIS shapefile

Tags: plotting, geography, geodesy

I have a dataset composed of points specified in {Latitude,Longitude} format. Call it `latlong` for the purposes of this question. It displays properly with

```
Graphics[{Point /@ 
   Map[GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[#], 
       "Mercator"][[1]] &, {latlong}, {2}]}]
```

I also have a shape file that contains the boundaries of the counties in which the `latlong` points reside. If I query `Import[demo.shp", "CoordinateSystemInformation"]`, I get

```
"GEOGCS" -> {"GCS_North_American_1983", 
  "DATUM" -> {"North_American_Datum_1983", 
    "SPHEROID" -> {"GRS_1980", 6.37814*10^6, 298.257}}, 
  "PRIMEM" -> {"Greenwich", 0.}, "UNIT" -> {"Degree", 0.0174533}}
```

and if I just `Import` the shape file, it displays correctly on screen.

I would like to display the points from `latlong` within the county borders from `demo.shp`. I have not been able to figure out how.

I appreciate that this is as much a GIS question as it is a Mathematica question, but I hope somebody here can help.

Comment: Can you upload `demo.shp` somewhere? Or just include a small sample of it

Comment: Assuming your latlong dataset and your SHP use the same datum I don't see a problem in combining the graphics resulting from both. What precisely is your problem?

Comment: The map invariably appears as a dot in one corner of the graph, and the points as a dot in the other corner. I suspect I'm messing up the projections. The data can be found at https://www.box.com/s/qw69but73asus7mig3j3  Let me know if you have any trouble accessing that folder, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Mathematica complains that it isn't an SHP file. (BTW don't forget to use the @name convention if you want to ping someone).

Comment: for a valid shapefile:.shp, .shx, .dbf are three Mandatory files

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries I didn't upload enough files. Check again; everything is in sample.zip.  Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelStern already solved it differently. See my answer.

Comment: related Q/A: [..plotting lat/long values](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2076/125)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most likely cause of your problem is that you are swapping lat and long coordinates.

Your latlong definition in the .NB file provided goes like this:

```
latlong = {{40.660323`, -73.997952`}, {40.660489`, -73.99822`}, {40.654365`, -74.004113`},...
```

That's New York. Simply plotting without projection gives:

```
m1=Graphics@Point@latlong
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I seem to see Long Island and some other familiar features. Looks like a subway map.

Here is a publicly available SHP map of the subway lines:

```
Import["https://wfs.gc.cuny.edu/SRomalewski/MTA_GISdata/June2010_update/nyctsubwayroutes_100627.zip", "SHP"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Extracting some coordinates from that:

```
Cases[map, {_Real, _}, Infinity]
```

> {{-74.015047, 40.703577}, {-74.015028, 40.703214}, {-74.014889, 
>     40.702506}, ...

You can see that this has the latlongs in the reverse order. Plotting these points with your other latlong gives precisely the result you describe above.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The solution is to map `Reverse` on these coordinates:

```
m2 = Graphics[{Red, Point@(Reverse /@ Cases[map, {_Real, _}, Infinity])}];
Show[m1,m2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The fact that the answer was so straight-forward doesn't make me any less impressed with how well you figured it out. I should have noticed that my dataset was placing Far Rockaway in the upper left, but somehow I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: nice detective work +1

Answer (score 4):

```
bg = Import["sample.shp"]
Show[bg, Graphics[Point@Reverse[latlong, {2}]]]
```

[image: output]

Comment: Totally correct, and thanks. Sjoerd C. de Vries beat you by a few minutes so I gave him the points.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with a map of the USA:

```
 plot1 = Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/usamap.zip","Graphics"]
```

[image]

Now we can add points on top of the map easily:

```
 points = Transpose@{RandomReal[{-100, -90}, 50], RandomReal[{35, 47}, 50]};

 Show[plot1,  ListPlot[points, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I might be wrong, but I assume the OP's problem is not in combining the graphics but it in taking care they use the same coordinate system. I don't believe you address that problem here.

Comment: correct, each renders correctly independently but placement and scale are very wrong when I combine them. I presume I'm messing up the coordinate system.