# {Latitude, Longitude} to Transverse Mercator projection

Tags: geodesy

I have a shapefile with the following `"CoordinateSystemInformation"`:

```
"PROJCS" -> {"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Illinois_East_FIPS_1201_Feet",
"GEOGCS" -> {
  "GCS_North_American_1983", 
  "DATUM" -> {
    "North_American_Datum_1983",
    "SPHEROID" -> {"GRS_1980", 6.37814*10^6, 298.257}}, 
  "PRIMEM" -> {"Greenwich", 0.}, 
  "UNIT" -> {"Degree", 0.0174533}}, 
"PROJECTION" -> {"Transverse_Mercator"}, 
"PARAMETER" -> {"False_Easting", 984250.}, 
"PARAMETER" -> {"False_Northing", 0.}, 
"PARAMETER" -> {"Central_Meridian", -88.3333}, 
"PARAMETER" -> {"Scale_Factor", 0.999975}, 
"PARAMETER" -> {"Latitude_Of_Origin", 36.6667}, 
"UNIT" -> {"Foot_US", 0.304801}}
```

I would like to plot {Latitude, Longitude} points and overlay these images, but I am having trouble converting coordinates. The shapefile data contains coordinates in the vicinity of {1.16328*10^6, 1.89271*10^6}. (This is Chicago.)

One point I would like to plot is {41.8713, -87.6737}.

```
GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{41.8713, -87.6737}], "TransverseMercator"]
```

gives the wrong coordinates:

```
GeoGridPosition[{-0.164851, 0.743066}, "TransverseMercator"]
```

As does

```
GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{41.8713, -87.6737}], "Mercator"]
```

which yields:

```
GeoGridPosition[{1.6114, 0.806147}, "Mercator"]
```

What am I doing wrong? It's not a question of reversed coordinates as in [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18311/plotting-a-latitude-longitude-list-on-top-of-a-gis-shapefile).

Comment: Could you please specify what would be the correct result in your example?

Comment: @belisarius I'm not certain what the numbers should be but the coordinates should be quite close to {1.16328*10^6, 1.89271*10^6}

Comment: Try `GeoPositionXYZ[GeoPosition[{41.8713, -87.6737}], "NAD83CORS96"]`

Comment: @belisarius That doesn't seem to do it. It gives me 3D coords (seeking 2d). And converting the 3D coords using GeoGridPosition does not yield answers in the right range.

Comment: Ok, it was just a try :(. Anyway, I fail to see what kind of 2D projection could give coordinates in that range (I don't know anything about Georeference!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The coordinates system of your shapefile is "NAD_1983_StatePlane_Illinois_East_FIPS_1201_Feet"

it is "SPCS83IL01" in GeoProjection Data

```
GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{41.8713, -87.6737}], "SPCS83IL01"]
```

This gives the coordinates in state plan system in **meters**, convert them into feet shall produce the right number you are looking for.

Comment: I modified the formatting of your answer so that the code is in a code block.  I shouldn't have changed the actual code, but please check just to make sure.

Comment: @Tuku Perfect, thanks! Meters should have been obvious but was throwing me off.

Comment: Wow! Finally, I found how to do this.  This means Maryland 1800 I will have to write SPCS83MD00