# City/Country Names by GeoLocation

Tags: curated-data, geography

How do I get the city and country names from the output of `FindGeoLocation[]` {lat, long} ?

Comment: This answer [How do I plot coordinates (latitude and longitude pairs) on a geographic map?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/how-do-i-plot-coordinates-latitude-and-longitude-pairs-on-a-geographic-map/2082#2082)  contains a related and useful function (`nearLC`) to find two nearest big cities (of population over 100000) for every geo-location point.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to do this:

```
nc = Nearest[
  CityData[#, "Coordinates"] -> # & /@ 
     CityData[{All, "United Kingdom"}]];
```

Then use this as:

```
nc[FindGeoLocation[]]
```

> {{"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}}

Comment: (I'm in the UK - your mileage might vary... :))

Answer (score 2):

The fastest is probably with the use of the [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) API*:

```
loc = FindGeoLocation[]
i = Import[
"http://api.geonames.org/findNearby?lat=" <> ToString[loc[[1]]] <> 
"&lng=" <> ToString[loc[[2]]] <> "&username=demo", "XML"];
name = Cases[i[[2, 3, 1, 3]], XMLElement["name", _, x_] -> x]
```

*Idea from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6370271/1420399).

**EDIT**: another option is the use of WolframAlpha plugin in mathematica:

```
WolframAlpha["near cities"]
(* or *)
= near cities
```

[image: wolframalpha output]

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Mathematica version 10.0 there is GeoIdentify function

```
GeoIdentify["Country", GeoPosition[{-11.00505177, -76.41350033}]]
```

Which results in

```
{Entity["Country", "Peru"]}
```

Comment: Of course you don't want to simply reproduce the Wolfram documentation, but it's worth pointing out that the first argument to `GeoIdentify` can be any one of a number of different kinds of entity, including "City".