# How can I list all the 'countries 4000 km far from current location'?

Tags: geography, geodesy

A friend said to me on Facebook that she is 4000km away. So I want to try to guess where she is.

How can I find which countries are a given distance from my current location?

Comment: Close reason: Wolfram|Alpha questions not related to Mathematica are off topic here.  Ask on http://community.wolfram.com/ instead.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I think this is an interesting question (we don't have any other answers on the site using `GeoDestination`) so I edited it to not be about W|A any more.

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't see why this is a W|A question. Mathematica has [the tools](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Geodesy.html) (and will even [have more in v10](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Geodesy.html)) to solve this question. I vote to reopen

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Because the OP specifically asked about Wolfram|Alpha (see the first version), and there's a good chance he might not even have Mathematica.  The question has been edited now.  While a Mathematica solution might not be useful for the OP, I agree that it is interesting, and it can be reopened, as others might ask the same.

Comment: @szabolcs I interpreted the first version as saying that W|A did not give an answer so that it was now up to Mathematica to come up with something. It might be that the OP was looking for a better way to ask W|A this. I guess both interpretations could be valid based on the rather ambiguous question.

Comment: @Sjoerd I think it doesn't really matter now.  The point is that people find it interesting and are writing answers that are sure to be useful for someone in the future.  So it will be reopened.  When I cast my close vote there were no answers.  You have my reopen vote now.  Regarding what the OP really meant when he asked it: I guess we'll never find out unless he speaks up! (looking at Boti :-) )

Comment: You can exploit a method used in this answer: [How do I plot coordinates (latitude and longitude pairs) on a geographic map?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/how-do-i-plot-coordinates-latitude-and-longitude-pairs-on-a-geographic-map/2082#2082), I mean the function `nearLC`.

Answer (score 23):

Thanks to [Simon Woods' advises](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50786/how-can-i-list-all-the-countries-4000-km-far-from-current-location/50794?noredirect=1#comment149812_50794) it should now be correct.

Taking the OP's informations:

```
loc = {46.72, 25.59};(*CityData["Gheorgheni","Coordinates"]*); 
dist = 4*10^6;(*distance in m*)

bounds = Table[GeoDestination[loc, {dist, i}][[1]], {i, 0, 360, 1}];
Graphics[{EdgeForm@Thin, Red, Polygon[Reverse /@ bounds], Opacity@.33,
    EdgeForm[Thin], FaceForm[LightGray], 
    Tooltip[CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"], #] & /@ CountryData[]}, 
  ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, the same can be done with your own location: `loc = $GeoLocation`.

`GeoDistance[loc, #] & /@ bounds` are then all equal to 4000 km.

---

Checking which countries are exactly on the 4000 km border (and thanks to rm-rf answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9417/1356)):

```
countriesCoor = 
  First /@ (CountryData[#, "Coordinates"] & /@ CountryData[]);
inPolyQ[poly_, pt_] := Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber[poly, pt] =!= 0
crossedCountriesPos = 
  Flatten@DeleteDuplicates[
    Table[Position[inPolyQ[#, bounds[[i]]] & /@ countriesCoor,True], 
      {i, 1, Length@bounds, 1}] /. {} :> Sequence[]];
crossedCountries = CountryData[][[#]] & /@ crossedCountriesPos;
crossedCountries // Short
insideCountries = CountryData[][[#]] & /@ 
  Flatten@Position[
  inPolyQ[bounds, #] & /@ (CountryData[#, "CenterCoordinates"] & /@
  CountryData[]), True];
insideCountries // Short
```

Countries lying on the 4000 km *border*:

> {Russia,Kazakhstan,China,Kyrgyzstan,Pakistan,Oman,Yemen, <<5>>,
>   Chad,Cameroon,Nigeria,Niger,Mali,Mauritania,WesternSahara}

Countries inside the 4000 km area:

> {Afghanistan,Albania,Algeria,Andorra,Armenia,<<73>>,
>   UnitedArabEmirates,UnitedKingdom,Uzbekistan,VaticanCity,WestBank}

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm@Thin, Red, Polygon[Reverse /@ bounds], Opacity@.33,
    Black, CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"] & /@ insideCountries, Blue, 
    CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"] & /@ crossedCountries, 
    FaceForm[Lighter@LightGray], 
    Tooltip[CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"], #] & /@ CountryData[]}, 
  ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Except the radius of that circle isn't 4000km?

Comment: Shouldn't the disk be also distorted like the map projection, or is that taken into account with geodestination ?

Comment: @blochwave I'm afraid that you are right indeed :) `GeoDistance[loc, endCircle]` doesn't even return 4000km.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes it's ~2000km indeed. I will fix it soon :)

Comment: Very nice, but to get the correct shape you need to keep `loc` as {lat, long} and do the `Reverse` **after** `GeoDestination`, i.e. `bounds = Table[Reverse@GeoDestination[loc,...`

Comment: @SimonWoods Please see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UGXgY.png)

Comment: The reversal of lat, long is only for displaying the graphics. Perhaps it is best to say don't reverse any coordinates in loc **or** bounds, and use `Polygon[Reverse /@ bounds]` in the graphics.

Comment: @SimonWoods D'oh of course. That's perfect thanks!

Comment: [Looks like](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoCircle.html) version 10 has this built in :-)

Comment: @Öskå - Hopefully, Boti's new friend doesn't live in Vatican-City.

Answer (score 15):

Using the new geographic tools in *Mathematica 10*:

```
GeoGraphics[
 GeoCircle[
  GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"Gheorgheni", "Harghita", "Romania"}]
   ],
  Quantity[4000, "km"]
  ],
 GeoBackground -> "StreetMap", (* To get country labels *)
 ImageSize -> 800
 ]
```

[image]

WRI posted another example [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/WolframResearch/status/491509359994994688).

There is another tool called `GeoIdentify` that returns all regions of the selected type that a path crosses. This can give us a list of countries to complement our visualization:

```
countries = GeoIdentify[
 "Country",
 GeoCircle[
  GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"Gheorgheni", "Harghita", "Romania"}]
   ],
  Quantity[4000, "km"]
  ]
 ]
```

Out:

[image: list of countries]

The `GeoIdentify` documentation has some ideas about how visualize this as well. Combining our previous code with this styling gives us:

```
geocircle = GeoCircle[
   GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"Gheorgheni", "Harghita", "Romania"}]
    ],
   Quantity[4000, "km"]
   ];
GeoGraphics[{
  (Tooltip[{GeoStyling[Opacity[.5]], RandomColor[], Polygon[#1]}, CommonName@#1] &) /@ countries,
  geocircle
  },
 GeoRange -> geocircle,
 ImageSize -> 800
 ]
```

[image: Stylish map]

If you think Spain doesn't look like it intersects the circle, recall the position of the Gran Canary Islands. (Since it is a popular tourist destination it's a good guess that that is where the OP's friend is.)

**EDIT:** Since the animation was generated I have replaced the tooltips according to rcollyers suggestion. The tooltip label is now the `CommonName` of the country entity instead of the entity itself (labels now look the way you expect them to.)

Comment: It would be nice to also *list* the countries in addition to plotting them.  Are there v10 tools for this?  (I don't know.)

Comment: @Szabolcs Well, you inspired me to keep looking and it turns out there is :)

Comment: Good use of v10! +1

Comment: Might I suggest you use [`CommonName@#`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CommonName.html) for the second argument in `Tooltip`? Oh, and you already had my +1.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks, I updated the code and wrote a short paragraph about this change.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you have Mathematica with you. So here's some quick and dirty way to get the info you require. I think it is very interesting to do this

```
currentLocation = 
 GeoPosition[
   CountryData[
     StringTrim[
      StringSplit[
        WolframAlpha[
         "Current GeoIP location", {{"HostInformationPod", 1}, 
           "ComputableData"}][[2, 2]], ","][[3]]], "CenterCoordinates"]];

 countries = CountryData[];
 geopos = GeoPosition[CountryData[#, "CenterCoordinates"]] & /@ countries;
 distances = GeoDistance[currentLocation, #] & /@ geopos;
 countriesAround4000km = CountryData[][[#]] & /@  Position[distances, _?(# < 4.1*10^6  && # > 3.9*10^6 &)]
```

Comment: `$GeoLocation` is easier than the W|A call.

Comment: I agree but it showed me wierd results at my end. Ok you can also try your approach if it works for you  `currentLocation = GeoPosition[FindGeoLocation[]];` without WA call

Comment: Well, both don't give the same location.

Comment: Agree.. the first approach derives the country of IP and then computes the center coordinates and other gives the current coordinates. Of course, a more detailed approach can be used