# Plot lat/long pairs on a US state map

Tags: geographics

I have a list of lat/long coordinates.  I'd like to plot them on a US state (say New York).  These coordinates include locations outside New York, but I'd like to get a map of just New York with these points shown.

I used an answer from [How do I plot coordinates (latitude and longitude pairs) on a geographic map?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2076/how-do-i-plot-coordinates-latitude-and-longitude-pairs-on-a-geographic-map/2080#2080) that allows me to plot these on the US.  It limits the US by using

```
 coords = CountryData["UnitedStates", "Coordinates"];
```

I tried using

```
coordsNY = 
  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"NewYork", "UnitedStates"}][
   "Cooridinates"];
```

But this seems to only give me one point - perhaps the centroid of the state?

Clearly I don't really understand the answer that I was trying to copy.  Perhaps there's another way to plot points on a specific US state.

Comment: try `nypolygon=
 Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"NewYork", "UnitedStates"}][
  "Polygon"]; Geographics@nypolygon`?

Comment: Take a look at [`GeoGraphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics.html), e.g. [this example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics.html#776466895)

Comment: Thanks kglr and Lukas I'm starting to get the hang of it.